# How to install NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (php version) without losing data preference

Tags: php, netbeans

I have NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 installed with all supported technologies like C, C++, Java etc which is approximately 205Mb and that hampers my PC's performance as it load very slowly. So I just want to install the PHP module which is only 64Mb.

How do I install only the PHP version without losing my data preference and projects?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a fresh install of your `IDE`, which can be done by:

- Find the `NetBeans Project` folder in `My Documents`
- Copy that to another location
- Un-install the `IDE` from `Control Panel`
- Restart you PC
- Download the `php` version **[here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=php)**
- Install it, start your `IDE` and just copy paste the project to the folder created in `My Document` for NetBeansProject

As far the preferences are concerned, if they are not very hard to create once again, a fresh install is good to go with as removal of the other modules like `C, C++, or Java` from `IDE` directly would still keep some files or cache(NetBeans version dependent) which would still hamper your PC sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

For installing Netbeans first of all you must have a latest version of Java  SDK installed on your PC.After that if you want to gain the data you must have the backup of the www folder which gets created while installation. After that  in Netbeans you can start a project and then copy-paste your created pages(php,html,css,js) in that project. And you are all set to start from where you left off.